# casting a floating to decimal in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not quite understanding the `cast` function and `decimal` here. What does `decimal(7,2)` actually mean?. `The first part and the second part arg of the function.`

Why do i need to `cast/convert` my floating point to decimal here?.

```
mysql> SELECT productCode, MAX(price), MIN(price),
              CAST(AVG(price) AS DECIMAL(7,2)) AS `Average`,
              CAST(STD(price) AS DECIMAL(7,2)) AS `Std Dev`,
              SUM(quantity)
       FROM products
       GROUP BY productCode;
+-------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
| productCode | MAX(price) | MIN(price) | Average | Std Dev | SUM(quantity) |
+-------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
| PEC         |       0.49 |       0.48 |    0.49 |    0.01 |         18000 |
| PEN         |       1.25 |       1.23 |    1.24 |    0.01 |         15000 |
+-------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+---------------+
```

Below is a sql fiddle for the same?.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ed51b/1/0

My Questions again repeated:

1. What does `decimal(7,2)` actually mean?. `The first part and the
   second part arg of the function.`
2. Why do i need to `cast/convert` my floating point to decimal here?.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DECIMAL(7,2)` means a number with a fixed decimal point, having 7 digits altogether, with 2 of them to the right of the decimal point. (So, 5 left, 2 right.)

You don't *need* to cast unless you want the behavior of DECIMAL types (typically, fixed point) rather than the behavior of FLOAT types (useful approximations with a relatively unpredictable number of digits right of the decimal point). For example, your average for product code "PEC" *with* the cast is 33333.65; *without* the cast it's 33333.653333.

If you're routinely using *all* the digits, you should probably increase the total number of digits in the cast. Say, to something like `DECIMAL (14,2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because if the intention is just to display the values, then casting to a DECIMAL with two decimal places will make it easier to read. If you take out the CASTs you will be shown values like `AVERAGE 33333.653333 STD DEV 47140.218734`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on `MySQL` manual:

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

If you use `decimal(M,D)` you are reserving no places for anything to the left of the decimal. `Decimal(7,2)` means `7-2 = 5` where `5` is your integer left and `2`  being on right.

**In simple words**, it describes how many total digits a field will be able to store. `Decimal(50,2) = 52 total digits`, `50 before` and `2 after decimal separator`.