# MySQL Multiplying float columns: 1*7.6 gives 7.599999904632568?

Tags: mysql, floating-accuracy, multiplication

When I make a query `SELECT 1*7.6` , It gaves me `7.6`

But when I make column multiplication (products.commision*sold.amount):

```
SELECT *,
(products.commision*sold.amount) as fee
FROM sold
RIGHT JOIN products
ON sold.idprod=products.ID
AND DATE(sold.date) BETWEEN DATE('2015-10-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31')
WHERE sold.userid="1"
ORDER BY sold.userid
```

It gaves me

```
ID | userid | date     | idprod | amount | Category | Name  | commision  | fee
60 | 1      | 15-10-01 | 21     | 1      | Volish   | Black | 7.6(float) | 7.599999904632568
```

Why?

Comment: You are using float columns. Decimal(19,6) is likely what you're looking for....

Comment: Probably because `products.commission` isn't exactly `1` or `sold.amount` isn't exactly `7.6`, but either value on it's own is close enough to be displayed as such.  Floating point numbers are tricky.

Comment: @Edward I don't understand?

Comment: Generally, money is DECIMAL, not FLOAT

Comment: @Mr.Llama It IS exactly 1 and 7.6 and I have to be precise

Comment: Your MySQL server is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: @Strawberry What's the difference? money is also a number?

Comment: oh wait i get it, float is binary

Comment: hmm I made these columns decimal but I can't set commision to 7.6? only 7 and 8?

Comment: it says it's decimal(10,0)?

Comment: [This answer by Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545617/892420) is a good way to think about the difference.

Comment: @Edward ye i just read it, now i know whats the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to type-cast the values as integers/Decimals rather than as floats when making the comparison so

```
(CAST(products.commision AS Decimal(7,2)) * CAST(sold.amount AS Decimal(7,2))) as fee
```

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html and [casting a floating to decimal in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357832/casting-a-floating-to-decimal-in-mysql)

The decimal sets the value as a decimal with the 7 digits the maximum size and the 2 digits the maximum precision (12345.67)

edit: I'm not sure if its more efficient to add the CAST to the raw values or to simply cast the answer such as

```
(products.commision  * sold.amount ) as CAST(fee AS Decimal(7,2))
```

Comment: changing column types is probably best overall strategy, but you can change these things in the query if this is an isolated issue.

Comment: one more question, if i have 17,56 it is 17,56, but when i have 18,00 i want it just 18. how do i do it?

Comment: where are you talking about? Where are these numbers, in the SQL query, or in the database, or?

Comment: If i have commision = `7.00` i want it to be `7`

Comment: But when it's `7.54` i want it to be `7.54`

Comment: for all intents and purposes `7.00` is exactly equal to `7`, if you're outputting the value to the browser then you can do some clearing up to remove excess zeros. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php

Comment: Oh i didnt know i can do it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help in comments,

**Solution**

Float is binary, and decimal is... decimal, so i changed my columns to decimal(16,9)